# Migration from wxPython to Phoenix

Tags: wxpython

While using wxpython 2.8 I had a convinient hack for the MainLoop
(source unknown)

```
def MainLoop(self):

# Create an event loop and make it active.  If you are
# only going to temporarily have a nested event loop then
# you should get a reference to the old one and set it as
# the active event loop when you are done with this one...        
self.evtLoop = wx.EventLoop()
self.oldLoop = wx.EventLoop.GetActive()
wx.EventLoop.SetActive(self.evtLoop)


# This outer loop determines when to exit the application,
# for this example we let the main frame reset this flag
# when it closes.
while self.keepGoing:
    # At this point in the outer loop you could do
    # whatever you implemented your own MainLoop for.  It
    # should be quick and non-blocking, otherwise your GUI
    # will freeze.
    #--------------------------------------
    # ##Here we put the code to be executed
    self.refresh()

    # This inner loop will process any GUI events
    # until there are no more pending
    while self.evtLoop.Pending():
        self.evtLoop.Dispatch()

    # Send idle events to idle handlers.  You may want to
    # throttle this back a bit somehow so there is not too
    # much CPU time spent in the idle handlers.  For this
    # example, I'll just snooze a little...
    time.sleep(0.005)
    self.ProcessIdle()

wx.EventLoop.SetActive(self.oldLoop)
```

so that the code in refresh() was executed every time. In the wxPhoenix Project wx.Eventloop changed to wx.GUIEvent (This change is nicely prompted by the core.py module http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.wxpython.devel/4804) but ProcessIdle() is also deprecated and for this no nice solution is mentioned.

digging into the source of wyPython 2.8 (_core.py) I find:

```
def ProcessIdle(*args, **kwargs):
"""
ProcessIdle(self) -> bool

Called from the MainLoop when the application becomes idle (there are
no pending events) and sends a `wx.IdleEvent` to all interested
parties.  Returns True if more idle events are needed, False if not.
"""
return _core_.PyApp_ProcessIdle(*args, **kwargs)
```

So I'm stuck there.

Any ideas?

Martin

Comment: I think your question title is vague and broad. A whole book could be written about "Migration from wxPython to Phoenix". Maybe change it to a narrow title that refers to your specific issue, such as "Migrate ProcessIdle() from wxPython 'Classic' to 'Phoenix'.

Answer (score 0):

Use the idle events in Phoenix for this purpose.

```
import sys; print sys.version
import wx; print wx.version()
if 'phoenix' not in wx.PlatformInfo: exit()


class CreateTestFrame(wx.Frame):
    """
    prove/test that Phoenix wx.EventLoopBase.ProcessIdle() sends events when transitioning into idle
    """
    def __init__(self):
        print "init a frame to test idle events"
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, "justAnIdleTest")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_IDLE, self.wentIdle)
        self.Show()

    def wentIdle(self, event):
        dlg = wx.MessageDialog(self,
            "Got idle event",
            "", wx.OK)
        result = dlg.ShowModal()
        dlg.Destroy()
        if result == wx.ID_OK:
            self.Destroy()

idleSandbox = wx.App()
testFrame = CreateTestFrame()
idleSandbox.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a sample in the Phoenix source tree that shows how to override the MainLoop: https://github.com/wxWidgets/Phoenix/blob/master/samples/mainloop/mainloop.py